# Expansion of $(z-1)^2 / (z-2)(z^2+1)$ in $z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to expand 
$$
f(z) := \frac { (z-1)^2 }{(z-2)(z^2+1)}
$$ around $z = 2$. I wanted to write $f(z) = \frac 1 {z-2} g(z)$ and then expand $g(z)$. Some hints would help a lot :)

Comment: Which annulus are you interested in? You've got two options: (1) $0<|z-2|<\sqrt5$ and $|z-2|>\sqrt5$. The answer will vary depending on which you choose.

Comment: I guess $|z-2| < \sqrt 5$ because my question wants the expansion around $z = 2$ and not away from $z = 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a good notion, but I suggest a slightly different approach. First, set$$\frac{(z-1)^2}{(z-2)(z^2+1)}=\frac{A}{z-2}+\frac{B}{z+i}+\frac{C}{z-i},$$ and solve for $A,B,C$. This is called *partial fraction decomposition*.

Next, note that for $z\neq\pm i$ we can write $$\frac1{z+i}=\cfrac1{z-2+2+i}=\frac1{2+i}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(-\frac{z-2}{2+i}\right)}$$ and $$\frac1{z+i}=\cfrac1{z-2+2-i}=\frac1{z-2}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(-\frac{2+i}{z-2}\right)}.$$

Now, one of these can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the annulus $|z-2|>\sqrt5$ and the other can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the annulus $0<|z-2|<\sqrt5$. That is, we will use the fact that $$\frac1{1-w}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^k$$ whenever $|w|<1$. You should figure out which annulus works for which rewritten version, and find the respective expansions in both cases. That will give you two different Laurent expansions, valid in two different annuli.

We can do something similar for $\frac1{z-i}$. Use that, and the partial fraction decomposition I mentioned above, to get the expansion for $f(z)$ about $z=2,$ in whichever annulus you prefer.

Alternately, you can use the decomposition $$\frac1{z^2+1}=\frac{i}2\left(\frac1{z+i}-\frac1{z-i}\right),$$ find the expansion of $\frac1{z^2+1},$ rewrite $$(z-1)^2=\bigl((z-2)+1\bigr)^2=(z-2)^2+2(z-2)+1,$$ which gives you the expansion(s) of your $g(z),$ etc.